# PHP extract from zip one file at a time

Tags: php, zip

I am using `$zip->extractTo()` to extract my zip file, this creates a new folder with all the files in it, I am just wondering if there is away I can extract the files one at a time and have them inside the root folder and not create a folder for me?

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($path) === true) {
    $zip->extractTo('../images/galleries/' . $galleryName);
    $zip->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getFromName` or `getFromIndex` methods to extract content from individual files, and then write to disk. For example:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip_filepath = '/path/to/zip/file';
$target_filepath = 'path/to/file/inside/zip';
$dest_filepath = '/path/to/extracted/file';

if ($zip->open($zip_filepath) === TRUE) {
  file_put_contents( $dest_filepath , $zip->getFromName( $target_filepath ) );
  $zip->close();
}
```